# How to show $G_{m}\cong G_n $ if and only if $n=m$, where $G_m:= \langle x,y \mid x(yx)^{m}=y(xy)^{m}\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I have this family of groups $G_{m}:= \langle x,y \mid x(yx)^{m}=y(xy)^{m}\rangle$. I want to show that for different $m$ these two groups are either isomorphic or not. 
My guess is they are not and I tried to show that via abelization but of course you get a trivial group for all $m$'s so that doesnt work. Any ideas how to show this?

Comment: Two downvotes and and two close votes but no comment : strange way to welcome a new user. The question is clear, the OP gave his guess on the question and his failed attempt. Why should this question be closed?

Comment: Yeah, im sorry if im doing something wrong, im new and I didnt fully grasp how this platform works. :)

Comment: Not sure if this helps but $x(yx)^m=(xy)^mx$. Setting $z=xy$ you get the presentation $$G_{m}:= \langle x,z \mid xz^mx=z^{m+1}\rangle$$

Comment: The question was unclear initially, @J.-E.Pin.

Comment: It seems to me the abelianization is not trivial, but rather isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ (which admittedly does not really help either with the question).

Comment: @Shaun Even with the initial question being unclear, commenting can help newcomers understand why their question is not well-received. Recommending the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) or [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) can give some more detailed information on how to improve a question that doesn't meet community standards.

Comment: Well, when I downvoted (which I have now removed), @Galen, there was a comment from another user detailing why they'd voted to close and had downvoted. That comment has been deleted, presumably in response to the edits it prompted.

Comment: Try looking at the groups you get (for different values of $m$) by factoring out the normal closure of $x^2$?

Answer (score 9):

Good question. Every such group $G_m$ is an *Artin group of spherical type* with the corresponding diagram $D$ given by two vertices connected by an edge labeled $2m+1$.

$$ 
\begin{aligned}
  \circ\!\overset{2m+1}{--------}\!\circ
\end{aligned}
$$

(You can read in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Tits_group) Wikipedia article about Artin, or Artin-Tits, groups.) An Artin group is said to be of spherical type if the associated Coxeter group is finite. In your case, the associated Coxeter group of $G_m$ is a finite dihedral group: It is obtained by adding the relators $x^2=1, y^2=1$ to the presentation.

It is known that Artin groups of spherical type are isomorphic if and only if their diagrams are isomorphic, this is the main result in:

*Paris, Luis*, [**Artin groups of spherical type up to isomorphism**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0310315.pdf), J. Algebra 281, No. 2, 666-678 (2004). [ZBL1080.20033](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1080.20033).

Hence, $G_n\cong G_m$ if and only if $n=m$.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a computational solution to complement Mishe Kohan's geometrical solution.

I will use the rewritten presentation $G_m = \langle x,z \mid xz^mz=z^{m+1} \rangle$.

Since the abelianization of $G_m$ is ${\mathbb Z}$ for all $m$, it has a unique subgroup $H_m$ of index 2, generated by $a:=z$, $b:=x^2$, and $c:=xzx^{-1}$.

It is straightforward to use the Reidemeister-Schreier method to compute a presentation of $H_m$, and we get $$H_m \cong \langle \,b,c \mid c^mb=a^{m+1},ba^m=c^{m+1} \rangle,$$ which simplifies (eliminating $b$) to $$H_m \cong \langle a,c \mid a^{2m+1} = c^{2m+1} \rangle.$$
So $H_m$ has abelianization ${\mathbb Z} \oplus \frac{{\mathbb Z}}{(2m+1){\mathbb Z}}$.

So the groups $H_m$ and hence also $G_m$ are pairwise non-isomorphic for $m \ge 0$.

It is easy to see that $G_{-m} \cong G_{m-1}$ for $m \ge 0$, so negative $m$ do not give new groups.